# Using Grunt Phonegap - how can you adjust some of the preference configs?

Tags: javascript, cordova, gruntjs

inside of the generated config.xml there is this setting `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />`

I need to set this to true, but I can't figure out how to override this. I added that to the iOS platform inside of _phonegap.xml but that didn't override it.

Comment: You worked for the NASA and you can't figure this out? Find where that config.xml is generated and you will be able to modify anything.

Comment: Please share your Gruntfile.js in question.

Comment: I figured it out, asked too quickly. Even though this is iOS specific, you can't nest this preference inside `<platform name="ios">`; also @thenchanter thanks for being super helpful. Modifying the generated config.xml file is a bad idea.

Comment: That's why I told you to find where the file is generated, so you don't have to modify the file itself but the data generating process. If you'd gone into the data generating process you would've seen which tag goes into which tag.

Comment: @thenchanter that's not it works. There are no platform iOS tags in the final output. Therefore you cannot draw the conclusion that you should not put tags inside of their in the template.

Comment: You can if you take a look at the config constructor. I'm teaching you to understand the tools you work with.